# How Do I Define the Return Type of this TS function?

Tags: typescript

I am working on a project, so this is not my original code. I have been asked to remove the warnings. I fixed a lot of TS warnings, but I can't figure out how to remove the warning on this TS function:

the warning is: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.`

```js
export function isElement(o: any): HTMLElement {
  return typeof HTMLElement === 'object'
    ? o instanceof HTMLElement //DOM2
    : o &&
        typeof o === 'object' &&
        o !== null &&
        o.nodeType === 1 &&
        typeof o.nodeName === 'string'
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `isFoo` probably returns `boolean` just by its name, right? Did you add that it returns HTMLElement? (Shouldn't it return `boolean` instead?)

Comment: The return type should either be `boolean` or `o is HTMLElement`. However, the `o && ...` part should be rewritten as `!!o && ...` so that the return value is definitely a `boolean`. (Typescript won't warn about this since `o` has type `any`, which is assignable to `boolean` on the assumption that the programmer knows what they're doing.)

Comment: Thank you @JeffBowman!

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you!